# Cannot search in lists

Tags: outlook-addin, harmon.ie

When I use Harmon.ie in Outlook 2013, I am unable to find results that are in a list on our SharePoint site, even if I browse to list and search directly on somthing I can see exist in my list.

http://oi60.tinypic.com/2qwm1aw.jpg

How come Harmon.ie cannot find contents of lists on my SharePoint Online 2013 site?

Comment: I'd suggest contacting Harmon.ie developers instead.

Answer (score 0):

Would you please download latest Harmon.ie version 4.5.2.xxxx) from Harmon.ie web site.
In the case, you still experience this issues, would you please run the same query (at the same scope) from SharePoint web Interface with IE.
If you get the expected result inside IE, please attach a screen shot and please gather the communication information between client (harmon.ie) and SharePoint server – we usually rely on Fiddler network tracing tool http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/ Please download and install it. If your Sharepoint site uses HTTPS secure protocol – after installing Fiddler, please go under ‘Tools -> Fiddler Options’, select ‘HTTPS’ tab and enable the checkboxes (Capture HTTPS Traffic, Decrypt HTTPS Traffic, Ignore Server Certificate Errors).
If installed and configured successfully – restart Outlook, and reproduce the problem (run the query) . You should requests being registered in fiddler. Once the trace log is generated, save it via File -> Save All Sessions… and attach the generated .saz file

---- Jean